# schema design union vs flat properties

Tags: graphql

when I have a parent Object type that needs to point to a child Object type but that child Object's type can be of several types and only one can be chosen and populated. I see 2 options I can do with regard to graphql schema design.

option 1 - use union

```
type child1{......}
type child2{......}
union chooseOne = child1 | child2
type parent{
         ref: chooseOne
}
```

option 2 use multiple props and have only one with data - the rest with nulls

```
type child1{......}
type child2{......}
type parent{
     ref1: child1
     ref2: child2
}
```

is there a 3rd option I am not thinking of? I am not that please with either. I feel like I am missing something... can anyone please comment? thanks! (edited)

Comment: union ... missing? ... array `recurrence : [Recurrence]`

Comment: @xadm , not sure I understand what you wrote. I have edited my post for better clarity. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> am I missing a third possible option?

using an array

```
type Meeting{
  .........(some properties)
  recurrences : [Recurrence]
}

union Recurrence = Once | WeeklyRecurrence | MonthlyRecurrence | DailyRecurrence
```

Of course it looks like a relation ... and it is ... and gives you more possibilities.

- all of them can have `validFrom` and `validUntil` times - you can filter out all historical entries automatically without manual disabling/removing
- you can have AND combinations instead OR, for example `'every working day at 10.00, additionally at 15.00 on fridays'`
- you can process recurrence entries separately f.e. for notifications (having meeting id just fetch attendees from another relation)

But in fact **maybe you don't need separate recurrence types at all**, only one field/property (enumerated types) to know which fields are required for render/forms/resolver/mutations etc.
... all of them can use the same DB table, the same record structures **in both cases** (types mapped to enumed type field).

## Update

I prefer 2nd option:

- it's more readable/debuggable
- it's easier to handle - `if(ref1)...<Ref1Component data={ref1}/>` ... passing union data object you don't have info about type!
- unions sometimes leads to troubles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59920824)

Comment: wow thanks for the elaborate answer...
but I think you missed out on my question(might be my fault). I have a general design problem I tried to illustrate through the reoccorence example (which I dont actually implement).
thanks anyway, I will try to maybe re-write my question so that its clearer.

Comment: I have edited my question again to make it totally general.... hopefully my question is more clear now. thanks